# Strange bug involving a list, "Objects of unequal length"

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, warning-messages

`sortedTally` is a list generated from `Tally`
`sortedTally[[1]][[1]]` is a list

If I print:

```
Print[sortedTally[[1]][[1]]]
```

> {A,C,G,T}

However, if I do either of the following:

```
 sortedTally[[1]][[1]]

 anotherlist = sortedTally[[1]][[1]]
```

I get the message

> Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in !({\"A\", \"C\", \"G\", \"T\"}\\ Null\\ {{{{0, 0, 0, 0}, 2}, {{1, 0, 0, 0}, 1}, {{0, 0, 1, 0}, 1}, {{0, 0, 1, 1}, 1}}}) cannot be combined"
>       Set::write: "Tag Times in anotherlist\ Null\ Null\ Null\ {0,0,0,0} is Protected."

My output is full of errors.

I don't understand why *Mathematica* prints it just fine, but complains here

Here is the code that can reproduce the error. I've tried resetting the kernel. That doesn't do anything.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
nWindows = 2;
Data = {{"A", "A", "A", "T", "A"}, {"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"}, {"T", 
"T", "G", "G", "G"}, {"A", "T", "T", "T", "T"}, {"G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G"}, {"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"}, {"G", "G", "G", "G", 
"C"}, {"A", "A", "T", "A", "A"}};
nreads = Dimensions[Data][[1]];
windowSize = nreads/nWindows;
DataCopy = Data;
For[i = 0, i < nWindows, i++,
  dataPortion = 
  Take[DataCopy, {windowSize*i + 1, windowSize*(i + 1)}];
  tDataPortion = Transpose[dataPortion];
  tally = Tally[tDataPortion];
  sortedTally = Sort[tally, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &];
  (*The Bug is here *)
  Print[sortedTally] (*this works fine *)
  Print[sortedTally[[1]][[1]][[1]]] (*this also works fine *)
  test1 = sortedTally (*this produces an error *) 
  sortedTally[[1]][[1]] (*this produces an error *)
  test3 = sortedTally[[1]][[1]] (*this produces an error *)
  (*end Bug *)
 ]
```

from `Print[sortedTally]` I get a list that looks fine to me:

> ```
>  {{{A,C,G,T},2},{{T,C,G,T},1},{{A,C,T,T},1},{{A,C,T,A},1}}
>   {{{G,C,G,A},3},{{G,C,C,A},1},{{G,C,G,T},1}}
> ```

Comment: Restart kernel, try it again. If that does not remedy, at least update OP with code and any static list content.

Comment: Without code , this cannot be answered in a meaningful way.

Comment: There is apparently a lot of junk in sortedTally (two lists connected with Null) you are not aware of. I guess Print prints everything before the Null and the simply stops. The other lines have trouble with the stuff in sortedTally.

Comment: Note `Print` returns `Null` and the statements of the last 5 lines are just multiplied together because there is no `CompoundExpression (;)` or other separator.

Comment: @ilian. `CompoundExpression` is a function and, therefore, its short form semicolon ( ; ) is an operator, not a separator. The only true separator in _Mathematica_ is comma ( , )

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes, absolutely -- 'other' was rather poor wording.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete. `windowSize` is undefined. I would also point out that `DataCopy = Data` does not make a copy of Data and, therefore, has no effect.

Comment: `Reverse@SortBy[Tally@Transpose@#, {Last}] & /@ 
 Partition[Data, windowSize, windowSize][[;; nWindows]]` will give you the set of results, you can then peek into them with `Part` et al. As an aside, avoid uppercase initials (e.g. `Data`), otherwise you run the risk of clashing with built-in symbols....

Comment: @m_goldberg I defined windowSize now, so it should be complete. I guess when I tested it windowSize must have been maintained in the kernel. I don't understand what the issue is with the last 5 lines. `x y` are multiplied, but they aren't if they are on separate lines. Is dataCopy not a copy because Data is a matrix?

Comment: @Chris St Pierre Take a look at how your `For` cycle is parsed: `Hold[For[...]] // InputForm`. The messages are due to evaluating `Print[sortedTally]*Print[sortedTally[[1]][[1]][[1]]]*test1 = 
     sortedTally*sortedTally[[1]][[1]]*test3 = sortedTally[[1]][[1]]`.

Comment: @chris I don't believe m_goldberg's statement regarding the copy to be correct.  He's right about the missing semicolons though.

Comment: Voting to close this again as the problem is, as Sjoerd points out, missing semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we have everything properly defined in your code, we can see that you problem is missing semicolons ( ; ). Beside pointing this out, I would like to also point out some ways in which your code can be improved.

My recommendations are:

1. Do not use global variables as  temporary varialbes.
2. Do not make assignments to global variables as a way of extracting data from you For-loop. Rather, wrap the loop in a module that returns the tallied data for further processing.
3. Limit your For-loop to making the tally. This keeps code simple and focused. You will be more likely not to introduce bugs as you did by doing everything in the For-loop. Any other processing needed can easily done afterward.

Applying these recommendations to your code reduces it to

```
tally = 
   Module[{dataPortion, tally = {}}, 
     For[i = 0, i < nWindows, i++, 
       dataPortion = Transpose[Take[Data, {windowSize*i + 1, windowSize*(i + 1)}]];
       tally = Join[Tally[dataPortion], tally]];
     tally]
```

> ```
>  {{{"G", "C", "G", "A"}, 3}, 
>   {{"G", "C", "G", "T"}, 1}, 
>   {{"G", "C", "C", "A"}, 1}, 
>   {{"A", "C", "T", "A"}, 1}, 
>   {{"A", "C", "T", "T"}, 1}, 
>   {{"A", "C", "G", "T"}, 2}, 
>   {{"T", "C", "G", "T"}, 1}}
> ```

Now the post-pressing is simple.

```
 sorted = SortBy[tally, Last] // Reverse
```

> ```
> {{{"G", "C", "G", "A"}, 3},
>  {{"A", "C", "G", "T"}, 2},
>  {{"T", "C", "G", "T"}, 1},
>  {{"G", "C", "G", "T"}, 1},
>  {{"G", "C", "C", "A"}, 1},
>  {{"A", "C", "T", "T"}, 1},
>  {{"A", "C", "T", "A"}, 1}}
> ```

```
First /@ sorted
```

> ```
> {{"G", "C", "G", "A"},
>  {"A", "C", "G", "T"},
>  {"T", "C", "G", "T"},
>  {"G", "C", "G", "T"},
>  {"G", "C", "C", "A"},
>  {"A", "C", "T", "T"},
>  {"A", "C", "T", "A"}}
> ```